# How to use LINQ to find all items in list which have the most members in another list?

Tags: linq

Given:

```
class Item {
    public int[] SomeMembers { get; set; }
}

var items = new []
{
    new Item { SomeMembers = new [] { 1, 2 } }, //0
    new Item { SomeMembers = new [] { 1, 2 } }, //1
    new Item { SomeMembers = new [] { 1 } }     //2
}

var secondList = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

I need to find all the `Item`s in `items` with the most of it's `SomeMember`s occurring in `secondList`.

In the example above I would expect Items 0 and 1 to be returned but not 2.

I know I could do it with things like loops or `Contains()` but it seems there must be a more elegant or efficient way?

Comment: What do you mean by "the most"? The largest value? The most frequent occurrence? It would really help if you'd give sample data and expected output.

Comment: Sorry Jon, I've amended the question to incorporate your comments and clarified the situation a little more. HTH?

Comment: Sort of - although the title still talks about "the most members" rather than "most of its members", which are two *very* different things.

Comment: Are you looking for "lists for which the majority of their members occur in a second list"?

Comment: @JerryFederspiel Yes. "Items where the majority of it's members occur in second list".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be written pretty easily:

```
var result = items.Where(item => item.SomeMembers.Count(secondList.Contains) * 2
                                         >= item.SomeMembers.Length);
```

Or possibly (I can never guess whether method group conversions will work):

```
var result = items.Where(item => item.SomeMembers.Count(x => secondList.Contains(x)) * 2
                                         >= item.SomeMembers.Length);
```

Or to pull it out:

```
Func<int, bool> inSecondList = secondList.Contains;
var result = items.Where(item => item.SomeMembers.Count(inSecondList) * 2
                                         >= item.SomeMembers.Length);
```

If `secondList` becomes large, you should consider using a `HashSet<int>` instead.

EDIT: To avoid evaluating `SomeMembers` twice, you could create an extension method:

```
public static bool MajoritySatisfied<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
                                        Func<T, bool> condition)
{
    int total = 0, satisfied = 0;
    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        total++;
        if (condition(item))
        {
            satisfied++;
        }
    }
    return satisfied * 2 >= total;
}
```

Then:

```
var result = items.Where(item => item.MajoritySatisfied(secondList.Contains));
```

Comment: (You may hate me but) I withheld some complexity in my question. Does your answer change significantly if `SomeMembers` actually involves a projection? Specifically a `SelectMany`? I can update the question to reflect this if not clear. I ask because `SomeMembers` is accessed twice.

Comment: Also to address your point regarding `HashSet`s, `secondList` will always be < 100.

Comment: @AdamNaylor: In that case you *may* want to separate that out into a separate method. Will edit that in.

Comment: @JonSkeet Putting your queries into LinqPad, I get `Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int'`for the first and `Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'method group'` for the second...

Comment: @germi: What's the type of `item.SomeMembers` in your test? If it's just `IEnumerable<int>` rather than `int[]` or `List<int>`, that would explain it...

Comment: @JonSkeet I just copied OP's code right into LINQPad. So it's a `int[]`.

Comment: @germi: Ah, got it - will fix.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah, now it makes sense. I should have gotten that myself :-/ Thanks for correcting it :)